# Play video in VideoView android

Tags: android, video

I want to play video in android without showing control bar and also want to set on loop video. so video will be played until user close that app. how can i implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here use this activity
           public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    Button btn_playvideo;
    VideoView vp_playvideo;
    MediaPlayer mp_playvideo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vp_playvideo=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vp_playvideo);

```
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.video/"+R.raw.rain;   
             Uri uri=Uri.parse(uriPath);
             vp_playvideo.setVideoURI(uri);
            /* vp_playvideo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    vp_playvideo.start();
                }
            });*/
             vp_playvideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                }
            });
             vp_playvideo.requestFocus();
             vp_playvideo.start();



}//end of create

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    vp_playvideo.stopPlayback();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```